# How to put listview inside a fragment

Tags: android, listview, crash, fragment

How can I put a  list view into a fragment? I use the default project setup with fixed tab.

It doesn't seem to work, and my app crashes.

Main activity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {
    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    public final static String PREFS_NAME = "UserData";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Only for safe mode 
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
        ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        /***********************************USER***************************/
        //Get User info (if exist)
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String id = settings.getString("id", "");
        String pass = settings.getString("pass", "");
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
        //Else create New User
        if (id == "")
        {
            System.out.println("Create New User...");
            UserRegistration.CreateUser(getApplicationContext());
        }
        /**** OTHER*****/
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 5 total pages.
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            case 4:
                return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l);   
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);       
            /***********************************CONTEST INC**********************
            String xmlURL;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            xmlURL = URL;
            System.out.println("Case 1");
            Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(XMLfunctions.getXML(xmlURL));
            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("contest");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
            {                           
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

                Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
                map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
                map.put("name", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
                map.put("subtitle",XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "subtitle"));
                mylist.add(map);
                System.out.println(mylist);
            }
            //new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, actions);

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.getActivity(), mylist , R.layout.contest_list, 
                    new String[] { "name", "subtitle" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

            ListFragment.setListAdapter(adapter);

            final ListView lv = getApplication().getActivity().getListView();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                }
            });



            /*************************************END CONTEST*********************/
            ContestList.GetList(getActivity(), 1, "mm", "njk");

            //TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                //  .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            String sectionNumb = Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
            int cat1;
            cat1 = Integer.parseInt(sectionNumb); 
            switch (cat1)
            {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            }   
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

ContestList class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ContestList {
    public final static String PREFS_NAME = "UserData";

    public static String GetList(Context context, int type, String id, String pass)
    {

        String xmlURL;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        xmlURL = URL;
        System.out.println("Case 1");
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(XMLfunctions.getXML(xmlURL));
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("contest");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
        {                           
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
            map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
            map.put("name", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
            map.put("subtitle",XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "subtitle"));
            mylist.add(map);
            System.out.println(mylist);
        }
        //new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, actions);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, mylist , R.layout.contest_list, 
                new String[] { "name", "subtitle" }, 
                new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        ((ListActivity) context).setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = ((ListActivity) context).getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                //Toast.makeText(Main.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            }
        });
        return "OK";
    }   
    public String adapter(ListAdapter adapter)
    {/*
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getApplication().getActivity().getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            }
        });*/
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

activity_main layout:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Fragment_main_dummy layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No data"/>

<TextView  
android:id="@+id/item_title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:padding="2dp"
android:textSize="20dp" />
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:padding="2dp"
android:textSize="13dp" />
```

Someone know why my app crash? or have an alternative for put a listview inside a fragment?

Thanks

EDIT:

Error log

```
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.time2win.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.ListActivity
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at com.time2win.ContestList.GetList(ContestList.java:50)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at com.time2win.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:241)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1012)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:881)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1366)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-20 12:53:31.219: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the crash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could use ListFragment for that. it's nicely explained in the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

also Vogela has tutorial on this:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments

Answer (score 7):

I got the output!!

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {

private String[] mNames = { "Fabian", "Carlos", "Alex", "Andrea", "Karla",
       "Freddy", "Lazaro", "Hector", "Carolina", "Edwin", "Jhon",
       "Edelmira", "Andres" };

private String[] mAnimals = { "Perro", "Gato", "Oveja", "Elefante", "Pez",
        "Nicuro", "Bocachico", "Chucha", "Curie", "Raton", "Aguila",
        "Leon", "Jirafa" };

int[] flags = new int[]{
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher  
};


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put("txt", "App Name : " + mNames[i]);
    hm.put("cur","creator : " + mAnimals[i]);
    hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) ); 
    aList.add(hm);        
}
String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur,R.id.textView2}; 

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container,false);
    ListView list = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);       
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
return v;
 }
 }
```

listview_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >    

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp" />          

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/cur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_top_rated.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

An example of a fragment that contains a list view with 3 elements. The key is the onCreateView, dont forget to inflate the fragment.xml(fragment_list) and within this one there will be a listView with an in of "listView$fragment_list$lista"

```
    public class FragmentList extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup   container,BundlesavedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    ListView lstItems = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView$fragment_list$lista);

    ArrayList<String> prueba = new ArrayList<String>();
    prueba.add("Element1");
    prueba.add("Element2");
    prueba.add("Element3");

    ArrayAdapter<String> allItemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,prueba);

    lstItems.setAdapter(allItemsAdapter);

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is due to trying to set the listadapter of the main activity instead of the list.

In your contest list class you do the following:

```
((ListActivity) context).setListAdapter(adapter);
```

But the context is not for ListActivity, it's for MainActivity.

You are doing it like this:

```
ContestList.GetList(getActivity(), 1, "mm", "njk");
```

But getActivity() means it returns the main activity which is "MainActivity".  You should rather change things to pass the listview in instead of the activity context or find another way to pass the data you need.