# Requesting logic for listview fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-fragments, rss

I'm making an activity with a listView fragment in it.  I am having a button click on the MainActivity load items for an rss feed that populate the listview fragment.

My question is, how should I go about setting it up? I already have the code for it.

My plan now is to have the button click on MainActivity point to my method in my RSSFragment which extends ListFragment.  I'm confused about some things like which activity to pass here:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Exception s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);

        lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Should I use getActivity()? or Pass MainActivity or RSSFragment.this?

Also, how do I set list adapter to a listview fragment?  Imagine lvRss isn't there.

I know it's a long question.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524275/how-to-put-listview-inside-a-fragment]

Comment: you can find your answer here.. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments

Comment: I appreciate it fellas.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use getActivity()? or Pass MainActivity or RSSFragment.this?

If you are in `Activity` the use `this` or `Activity.this` . IF you are in `Fragment` the use `getActivity()`.

> Also, how do I set list adapter to a listview fragment? Imagine lvRss isn't there.

Use [setListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)) method setting `Adapter` to `ListFragment`